# Return the THIRD smallest element in a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I'm trying to write a program (in python2.7) that receives a list of integers and returns the third smallest integer in the list using iteration. If there are two integers it returns the higher one. If there is only one integer, it returns that. If there are none, it returns none.
I'm super confused and I don't know how to write this. I made an attempt here:
UPDATED VERSION:

```
s = raw_input("Enter your list:")
L = list(s)
sorted(L, key=int)
return [2]

if len(L) = [0:2]
return [1]

if len(L) = [0]
return 0

if len(L) = []
return none
```

However, I'm having some difficulties with this. Any suggestions on how to modify it to get it to do what I want? I know of the heap function, but I'm trying to write it without using that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sort the list, then return the third one, or the last one if the length of the list is less than 3.

Comment: What do you expect `if s is (a, b):` to do? You haven't assign the variables `a` and `b`. And that's a new list, it will never be the same as another list.

Comment: If you want to know the length of the list, use `if len(L) == 2:`. Why are you using `s` in the function instead of `L`? And why do you return `sys.maxint` instead of the higher one?

Comment: It seems like you haven't really thought this through at all, you're just throwing random code together.

Comment: For the record, in real code, I'd skip sorting in favor of `heapq.nsmallest`, which only does `O(k log n)` work (where `k` is the number of smallest items to pull, and `n` is the full list length) instead of `O(n log n)`. By indexing the result using `-1`, you don't need to special case list sizes of 1 or 2; heck, you could even get clever and do `(heapq.nsmallest(3, L) or [None])[-1]` so you handle empty lists (and non-list inputs where you can't precheck the length) seamlessly.

Comment: `def thirdSmallest(L): return (sorted(L)[:3] or [None])[-1]`.

Comment: Hmm...  Correction: `nsmallest` is `O(n log k)`, not `O(k log n)` (and the `O(k log n)` approach would actually be `O(max(n, k log n))` given the heapify operation). [It maintains an `n` element heap as it iterates the input performing replace operations over and over as it finds new small enough values](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Lib/heapq.py#l4610), so it does `O(n)` heap replacements (usually far less than `n`, but big-O assumes pathological case), each costing `log k` work. Bonus: It can stream a huge number of values, using memory for only `k` values.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
def thirdSmallest(L):
    # sort the list from smallest to largest
    L.sort()
    # select the 3rd element, or if less than 3 elements exists,
    # select the last one of the sorted list.  If the list is empty return None
    return (L[:3] or [None])[-1]
```

Comment: You just need a special check for an empty list first.

Comment: You can simplify the non-empty case to `return L[:3][-1]` which handles 1, 2 and 3+ cases equivalently. Or even better, `return (L[:3] or [None])[-1]` which handles the empty case too.

Comment: That is very clever.  I will update.

Comment: See my answer below. `heapq.nsmallest` is more efficient than sorting for small values of `n`. You should also consider using `(None,)` instead of `[None]` as tuples are lighter and quicker to build.

Answer (score 1):

ShadowRanger is correct. You should use [heapq.nsmallest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest):

```
import heapq

def third_smallest(x):
  return (heapq.nsmallest(3, x) or (None,))[-1]
```

---

If you're looking for a highly performant option, using a PriorityQueue implementation of a [heap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) would likely be the best.

Building the heap should take O(n) time and then just pop off the top three elements O(log n). The final time complexity is O(n + log n) versus using a sort O(n log n).

Your solution would look something like:

```
import heapq

def third_smallest(x):
  heapq.heapify(n)
  value = None
  try:
    for i in range(3):
      value = heapq.heappop(n)
  except IndexError:
    pass
  return value
```

This can proably be improved.

Comment: `heapq.nsmallest` already does this work for you; the minor benefit of avoiding the length three list it makes is not work reimplementing it.

Comment: Oh true, the documentation even says that it performs best on smaller values of n. I also missed that `heap.nsmallest` is equivalent to `sorted(iterable, key=key)[:n]` and wasn't sure that they'd be ordered.